# How to fix VercelEerror python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully

Tags: python-3.x, django, pip, vercel, requirements.txt

I'm trying to deploy a Django web app on Vercel, but the deployment fails with the following message:

```
Error: enter code hereCommand failed: pip3.9 install --disable-pip-version-check
--target . --upgrade -r /vercel/path0/requirements.txt   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
     × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.   │ exit code: 1   ╰─> [23 lines of output]
      running egg_info
      creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-xergdc3a/psycopg2.egg-info
      writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-xergdc3a/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-xergdc3a/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-xergdc3a/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
      writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-xergdc3a/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      
      Error: pg_config executable not found.
      
      pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
      containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
      option:
      
          python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
      
      or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
      
      If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
      'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
      
      For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
      <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
      
      [end of output]
     note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. error: metadata-generation-failed
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: https://github.com/vercel/vercel/discussions/5186

Comment: I copied the psycopg2 folder as suggested but the error does not resolve

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the dependencies in requirement.txt and downgrading the psycopg2-binary version to an older version

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).